# Bootstrap Media Component Formatting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the media component to have an image on the left with a  description to it's right. The image is stuck to the left side of the screen though. To add a gap there, I need to use padding but that messes up the mobile version that bootstrap components are compatible with. How can I do this without ruining the mobile version of bootstrap?

Thanks.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Projects</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a href="index" class="navbar-brand">Zarwan Hashem</a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
               <li class="active"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
               <li><a href="resume">Resume</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-right">zarwan@zarwanhashem.com</a>
       </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="media">
         <a class="pull-left" href="#">
            <img class="media-object" src="robotAI.png" alt="...">
         </a>
         <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
                  Testing test test
         </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

CSS (The 55em padding is just so I can try to see if it'll change anything):

```
body {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     padding-bottom:150px;

}

img {
    padding-left: 55em;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
    img {
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
} 

p {
  margin-right:15em;
  padding-top:0;
  font-size:1.2em;
}
```

Comment: I tried padding. This is the webpage: zarwanhashem.com/projects I took the padding away now though @Phani

Comment: we need to actually be able to see the code, this is just expecting strangers on the internet to solve your problem without actually showing us what you've tried - probably not going to happen

Comment: You can see the code if you use inspect element, can't you? I'll add it into the first post though. @AnindyaBasu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIRST SOLUTION**

Add `padding` depending on your screen size using `@media` queries like this:

```
img {
    padding-left: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
    img {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
}
```

**SECOND SOLUTION**

It is considered best practice to have a wrapper for your content that will be 80% or 90% of your page width and to center with `margin: 0 auto;`. Then use `@media` queries to adapt your `wrapper` width depending on the screen size (so for example for mobile devices).

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* to center your content in the middle of the page */
}
img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
.wrapper p {
  display: inline-block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this not padding it if I'm on mobile? So it's still stuck to the side? This is the first time I've seen this type of thing (queries).

Comment: What the code does is to have a `padding` at 0px (so no padding) for any screen below 48em width (mobile devices for example) and then add a padding for screen larger that 48em. Adjust the size depending on your need. You can learn more about `@media` queries here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: The media query seems nice, but when I try changing the 0px default and access the site on my phone nothing is changing. Also, for your second solution, you're saying that I shouldn't use the media component at all? Or that I should "wrap" it?

Comment: Can you post the css you have so far?

Comment: Thanks. Just replace your `padding-left: 55em;` (on your image) by `padding-left: 0;`. Then try resizing your screen.

Comment: @user3641545 I've edited the code for the second solution to show you how `@media` queries could work in this situation. Try it in your code and resize your browser.

Comment: So would the wrapper go inside or around the media block? i.e. <wrapper goes here><media>stuff<end brackets> or <media><wrapper>stuff<end brackets>?

Comment: You are right, it should go **around** the media block (<wrapper><media>stuff</media></wrapper>>) so that you can add as many elements as you want inside. All elements inside your wrapper will be aligned that way.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to have an un-minified version of bootstrap.css to learn from and to understand what styles are used on various components and elements.

**The `.media` component is NOT responsive it is fluid. It has no media queries.**

If you want to not affect smaller viewport displays of this component, you would look at the css see what you need to change and make a media query at the MIN width of your choice. So you don't affect other uses of the `.media` component you would use a custom class (anything you want):

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .media.custom .pull-left {padding-left:80px}
}
```

This is using pixels to match the bootstrap.css default sizes. If your bootstrap.css is using em, then adjust.

```
<div class="media custom"> ...
```

**Demo: http://jsbin.com/nopani/**

Comment: So I basically need to make custom adjustments with padding for different screen sizes?

Comment: I don't know how you're using this. You can use percentages as padding too. min-width is from 768px and up until forever unless there's another min-width media query following this with adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

I would say don't use padding because it'll make things messy and hard to keep track of, instead center the media div on the page.

You need to do this in css, something like

```
.media {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You can always change `.media` to any `@media` query to target a specific device/screen size.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood your solution, or you misunderstood my question. I'm trying to indent the image to the right, not move the text to the right relative to the image. Isn't this just centering my text?

Comment: it centers everything in the "media" div so the image and the text.

Comment: I tried adding this into my code but only the text was being centered. The image is still stuck to the left side.